# Переходит в другой активити со 2 раза

Tags: java, android, activity

По нажатию кнопки Login ничего не происходит, но если нажать второй раз переходит в ProfileAct активити.

Код:

```
package ru.network;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private EditText  login , pass;
private Button mSubmit, mRegister;


private static String Data;

public static void NmSN(String data){
    Data = data;
}
// Progress Dialog

// JSON parser class
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

// php login script location:

// localhost :
// testing on your device
// put your local ip instead, on windows, run CMD > ipconfig
// or in mac's terminal type ifconfig and look for the ip under en0 or en1
// private static final String LOGIN_URL =
// "http://xxx.xxx.x.x:1234/webservice/login.php";

// testing on Emulator:
private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://nw.pe.hu/******.php";

// testing from a real server:
// private static final String LOGIN_URL =
// "http://www.mybringback.com/webservice/login.php";

// JSON element ids from repsonse of php script:
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "ifAuth";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // setup input fields
    login = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

    // setup buttons
    mSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    mRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);

    // register listeners
    mSubmit.setOnClickListener(this); 
    mRegister.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stubs
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.login:
        new AttemptLogin().execute();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}

class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Check for success tag
        int success;
        String username = login.getText().toString();
        String password = pass.getText().toString();
        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", password));

            Log.d("request!", "starting");
            // getting product details by making HTTP request
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST",
                    params);

            // check your log for json response
            Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

            // json success tag
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {

                Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                // save login data

                SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
                Editor edit = sp.edit();
                edit.putString("username", username);
                edit.commit();
                new AttemptGetData().execute(json.getString("ID"));
                JSONObject jsone = new JSONObject(Data); 
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProfileAct.class);
                i.putExtra("ID", json.getString("ID"));
                i.putExtra("name", jsone.getString("name"));
                i.putExtra("surname", jsone.getString("surname"));
                i.putExtra("avatar", jsone.getString("avatar"));
                finish();
                startActivity(i);



                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Неверный логин и\"или пароль!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted

        if (file_url != null) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}

}
```

main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/register"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/login"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/login"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
    android:text="Register" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/register"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/password"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/password"
    android:text="Login" />

<EditText
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/login"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:ems="10"
     >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Android Remote Server Tutorial"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textStyle="bold" />



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/password"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/password"
    android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
    android:text="Пароль" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:ems="10" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Login" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы используете вызов другого `activity` внутри `doInBackground` и вызываете `activity`

```
finish();
startActivity(i);
```

тут получается, целостность `AsyncTask` тут портится. предлогаю, вызывать другую activity в функции onPostExecute 
или еще лучше создать вызыва другого `activity` в функции класса `MainActivity`

К Примеру:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

...

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stubs
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.login:
        new AttemptLogin(this).execute();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}

public void gotoProfileAct(String id, String name, String surname, String avatar){
  Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProfileAct.class);
  i.putExtra("ID", json.getString("ID"));
  i.putExtra("name", jsone.getString("name"));
  i.putExtra("surname", jsone.getString("surname"));
  i.putExtra("avatar", jsone.getString("avatar"));
  finish();
  startActivity(i);
}

}

class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

private MainActivity mainActivity;
public AttemptLogin(MainActivity  mainActivity){
  this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
} 

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

}
```

....

```
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    // dismiss the dialog once product deleted

    if (file_url != null) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
 mainActivity.gotoProfileAct(id, name, surname, avatar);
}
```

Comment: А как получить данные(id, name...) из AttemptLogin()?

Comment: Вариантов много. 1) сделать 4 переменных в классе `AttemptLogin` и при парсинге перезать значении этим переменным. 2) следать `json` переменную глобыльном в классе `AttemptLogin`

Comment: Сделал, но теперь вообще не переходит

Comment: можеш показать код? Может еще что то другое появилось?

Answer (score 0):

Метод doInBackground выполняется в фоновом треде, там должны выполняться только длинные операции, такие как запрос на удаленный сервер, а обработку результата и переход на новый активити нужно делать уже в главном треде.

Answer (score 0):

Вот это:

```
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProfileAct.class);
            i.putExtra("ID", json.getString("ID"));
            i.putExtra("name", jsone.getString("name"));
            i.putExtra("surname", jsone.getString("surname"));
            i.putExtra("avatar", jsone.getString("avatar"));
            finish();
            startActivity(i);
```

Вызывай из главного потока. Самый простой способ у Activity есть метод runOnUiThread, принимает Runnable. Либо в onPostExecute.

```
mainActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // код
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Как уже было сказано проблема заключается в том что startActivity вызывается не в гуевом потоке. Есть несколько вариантов решения этой проблемы:

1. Возвращать в onPostExecute Intent вместо String для этого ваш **AttemptLogin** должен наследовать `AsyncTask<String, Void, Intent>`

PS так же можно создать [POJO](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/POJO) класс, который будет содержать все поля которые вы складываете в интент. А уж создание интента по этому классу реализовать в onPostExecute. Это более правильный вариант.

2. Либо как предложил [Алексей Мальченко](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/431031/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE-2-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0/431042#431042) завернуть все это в главный поток. Это можно сделать множествами вариантами. Но это не совсем правильно.